# Python - return value shift between frames

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, frame

In the following code, I have some difficulties in understanding how the return value is shifted between the scopes of the functions.

```
def x(y):
    def y(z):
        x = lambda x: x**2
        y = lambda x: x+2
        def z(x):
            return x(5)
        return z(y)
    return y(x)
print(x(lambda x: x+1))
```

I understand that the return value is evaluated to be 7 since `y = lambda x: x+2` is passed into `z(x)` where 5+2 = 7. I ran my code through Visualize Python to understand how it works and I do not understand the last three steps.

Step 16 of 18:
[image]

Step 17 of 18:
[image]

Step 18 of 18:
[image]

Would really appreciate it if someone could enlighten me on what is going on here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

16. `z` returns `7` because in the scope of `f2`(or in the `def y(z):` zone), `y` points to
    `lambda x: x+2`, and `z` returns `y(5)`. `y` was assigned in line 4. (This is represented by the blue arrow in the first image)
17. `y` (or `f2`) simply returns what the function `z` (belonging to the frame of `y`/`f2`) returns. Don't be tricked by the notation `z(y)`. Because the `y` in the parenthesis is `lambda x: x+2`, as `y` has been reassigned to that value. So `y` returns also `7`.
18. `x` (or `f1`) returns what the `y` belonging to the scope of `x` (or `f1`) returns. `y` in the scope of `x` (or `f1`) happens to be `f2` and it returns `7`.
    So `x` or `f1`, will return `7`.

If something is still unclear, let me know what part.

Comment: Okay, this made it a lot clearer for me to understand. Thank you for your explanation :)